# How to create custom filter

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have a doubt, in my filters I need that, when clicking on a color, for example BLUE, it opens the variations of BLUE below (Navy Blue, Dark Blue..) I thought about making 2 attributes, one as master color, and another as a secondary color, however, I can't figure out how to display this. So that when you click on the color, it displays the secondary colors below. How can I do this? Is there a search engine that can help me, or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported by default. You need custom changes to reach your goal. You should create 2-nd attribute as you mention => this is correct approach.

Then you need to prepare mapping. So assign `navy blue` to `blue`. You have 2 options:

- manually mapping in php file
- use `system.xml`, add new dynamic table property, define there 2x dropdown with your attributes and based on this data you can build this mapping as well

Then you should override the `layeredNagiation` module. Hide by default your sub-color by code. And show it only when match to created mapping. So get the active filter, look for correct sub-colors and display them.